# Guidance on cables in parallel from visualisation

Tags: power-supply, network

[image]I've been told cable 1 is in parallel with cable 2 and 3 yet I'm not visualising it just yet. Could someone clarify whether it's that from the source there are 2 paths? Cable 1 and cable 2-3. Thanks

[image: The diagram of network]

[image: Could you also explain what is parallel and in series for this]

Comment: When Lines and Returns are shared with multiple feeders from the same point, consider that in parallel.  But when separated by different drops for each feed, there is series +  parallel  network  (e.g. lights) So (2) is series with (3) and both are parallel with (1)

Comment: so in image 1. heating in parallel with motor and the lights. ive added extra pic to explain

Comment: Parallel means shared identical net voltage

Comment: i see so for image 2 then.. using your explanation, 1+2 in series. 3 parallel??

Comment: sorry 2 + 3 in series as share same point... 1 paralel?

Comment: If measured at the same node, yes in parallel

Comment: sorry could you explain image 2 again. whats in series and whats in parallel. thanks

Comment: In 2nd diagram, Node (1) would see two parallel loads yet  the load measured at (2) and (3) do not account for each series line losses of each feed if measured as parallel loads at (1) Yet if lengths and impedances are known can be predicted

Answer (score 0):

Do the lights and motor look to be in parallel now?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feYwn0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Although the two cables are not geometrically parallel, their loads are considered to be *electrically* parallel.  Electrical schematics have no relationship whatsoever with geometric layout. Electrical schematics show how wires and components are interconnected.

I have added the labels A and B to some nodes in the circuit. Notice that  one can trace a continuous path from A to B in several ways.

One can trace a path from A through cable 1, through the heating system, back through cable 1 to node B.

One can also trace a path from A through cable 2, through the motor, back through cable 2 to node B.

Since those two paths have both start and end with the same node, and since neither of the paths contain any branches leading elsewhere, these two paths are said to be *electrically* parallel.

Comment: im sorry i don't understand. was told cable 1 in parallel with 2 and 3. yet in your diagram cable 1 is lights not heating. could you dumb it down for me. maybe draw on top original image

Comment: The original image is no help, because it hides the fact that there are two wires,  in a single cable, and thus fails to show how the wires are connected together. I fixed the label that did say "lights" to say "heating". Do you understand that the heating and the motor are _electrically_ parallel, even though they are not geometrically parallel?

Comment: yeah thats where im tripping up. i dont understand that. could you maybe use image 2 as example

Comment: No, I cannot use image 2. Again, it represents 2 distinct wires as a single cable, which hides how the wires are interconnected. Electrical schematics have no relationship whatsoever with geometric layout. Electrical schematics show how wires and components are interconnected.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 ph means 3 wires for 3 phase power.

There are 3 wires going to a panel.  Off the panel is:

- a 3-phase 3-wire 22.5kW heating load, 75m from panel.
- a 3-phase 3-wire 50kW, pf 0.9 lagging motor, 150m from panel.

Off the motor there is a:

- 3-phase 3-wire 5kW, pf 0.7 lagging light load, 100m from motor.

Image is single line (because extra lines would not make the problem any clearer), but all loads are connected in parallel, so each load gets approximately 415V.

It's approximately 415V because wire has resistance and depending on current, some potential is lost to the wires meaning voltages at loads will be lower.